# connecting a select tag to a form, and then reseting it at submit

Tags: reactjs, select, submit

hi guys I'm trying to reset a select tag after the submit using React,I connected the first option to the state which is :

```
state = {
    inputs: [],
    tempInput: {

       inputType: 'Please select a type'

    }
  };
```

so I basically select a type in my form, it updates the tempInput object with the inputType, and then add it to the array of objects,

```
 <div className="formG">
            <form className="form-maker" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
               <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
                <option>{this.state.tempInput.inputType}</option>
                <option value="text">text</option>
                <option value="color">color</option>
                <option value="date">date</option>
                <option value="email">email</option>
                <option value="tel">tel</option>
                <option value="number">number</option>
              </select>

              <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
```

this is my on select method:

```
onSelect = ({ target }) => {
    const { tempInput } = this.state;
    tempInput.inputType = target.value;
    this.setState({ tempInput });

  };


handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
how to do that in handleSubmit? to put the tempInput.inputType to ="Please pick a type"
  };
```

Comment: Why don't you `setState` this `tempInput.inputType to ="Please pick a type"` in handleSubmit

Comment: Like I did on the onSelect?

Comment: yes, doing that should reset the select

Comment: that solution doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [uncontrolled element](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components). 
If you want to control the value of an `input` / `select` you need to set it via your state:

```js
const values = [
  "text", "color", "date", "email", "tel","number"
]

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "" };

  onSelect = ({target}) => this.setState({value: target.value})

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('submit with ',this.state.value)
    this.setState({value: ''})
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
          <option>Select A value</option>
          {values.map(val => <option key={val} value={val} selected={val === value}>{val}</option>)}
        </select>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        <div>{`Selectet Value is ${value}`}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Here is the example without the array:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "" };

  onSelect = ({ target }) => this.setState({ value: target.value })

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('submit with ', this.state.value)
    this.setState({ value: '' })
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
          <option selected={value === ""} value="">Select A value</option>
          <option selected={value === "text"} value="text">text</option>
          <option selected={value === "color"} value="color">color</option>
          <option selected={value === "date"} value="date">date</option>
          <option selected={value === "email"} value="email">email</option>
          <option selected={value === "tel"} value="tel">tel</option>
          <option selected={value === "number"} value="number">number</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        <div>{`Selectet Value is ${value}`}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Of course there is a lot of repeated code here, in programming there is the "DRY"  principle (Do Not Repeat Yourself).
This is why we use loops like [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I'm sorry your solution is a bit to advance for me, can you give me a simple example without the arrays?

Comment: ok thank you, but I still don't see where did you connect the state to the <select> tag, I mean how does it resets?

Comment: is it the selected property? I mean, in inputs there is value that is connected to the state, what is connected here?

Comment: yeah exactly, with the `selected` attribute. its the DOM attribute for an `<option />` nothing related to react. but now we are controlling it instead of the end user

Comment: but why did you add selected to every single option?

Comment: read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes) for this element

Comment: because its an attribute of the `<option/>` element,  its like asking why to put a `value` attribute on each of your `<inputs />`. because we want to control its value

Answer (score 1):

in your onSelect function, you're mutate the state object(`tempInput.inputType = target.value;`), it is not a good practice in react.

if you want your select value controlled by the react state, first you need to bind it's value with react state, which it's called a controlled component, like:

```
<select onChange={this.onSelect} value={this.state.tempInput.inputType}>
```

Comment: as far as I know, I don't mutate a state object, I make a copy of him and then place it back. or am I wrong?

Comment: @AlexAlex in your case, const { tempInput } = this.state;  this line of code is not copy tempInput object, it just copy the object reference to the variable named tempInput. so when you do: tempInput.inputType to ="Please pick a type", you are still mutate the origin state.tempInput. hope this make it clear

Comment: are you sure about that? because I was told this was the way to change the state by a user in stackoverflow, so I'm confused.

Comment: @AlexAlex have a look of this, https://codepen.io/stevejiachen/pen/QZwoXW?editors=1010.  open the console tool, you can see the origin state been mutated, even i did not set it

Comment: ok I see, but I dont understand your way, how do you change the state?

Comment: basically, you don't have to create a variable of your state and then modify it, in your case just update state like this:
this.setState({tempInput: {inputType: e.target.value}});